# Overriding a public final static frozen set in Java/Gosu?

Tags: java, reflection, set, final, gosu

I have a set declared static final and is additionally frozen.

```
class MyParent {
    public final static var MY_FIELDS : Set<MyParent> = {
        FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5
    }.freeze()
}
```

Now, because the MyParent.MY_FIELD is called from multiple locations to do some magic stuff, I wish to take over the advantage of this and simply override the collection itself.

```
class MyChild extends MyParent {
    public override static var MY_FIELDS : Set<MyChild> = {
        FIELD1, FIELD3, FIELD5, FIELD8, FIELD9, FIELD10
    }.freeze()
}
```

I also tried using the `new` keyword as it's done in .NET.

```
class MyChild extends MyParent {
    public new static var MY_FIELDS : Set<MyChild> = {
        FIELD1, FIELD3, FIELD5, FIELD8, FIELD9, FIELD10
    }.freeze()
}
```

However, no workaround worked so far. Then, I read that it's feasible through reflection.

- [`Java Hacks - Changing Final Fields`](http://zarnekow.blogspot.ca/2013/01/java-hacks-changing-final-fields.html)

And then, I can't access to the `getClass()` method or `class` member of my type, neither `MyParent`'s.

*Is there any workaround that would allow me to achieve this, and how?*

Using Gosu 8.0 in a Guidewire project.

Comment: You should not fight against your programming language. Besides that, it seems you don’t know what you actually want. Do you want to modify the parent’s field, do you want to override it or do you want to create a new field with the same name? All three things are mentioned in your question. And none of them is able to solve whatever your problem is, as they all imply that you want a `static` variable (I’m even not talking about its immutable nature here) to do what `static` variables don’t do.

Comment: Actually, all I want is to override the value returned by the static variable through the derived class, so instantiating the derived class will allow for the static variable to return fields that are specific to it.

Comment: That’s simply impossible as it contradicts what `static` variables are: variables which exist *exactly once*. Being defined in a class provides a namespace and access rules, but in principle, each `static` variable is just a global variable. As said, the fact that the variable is `final` isn’t even relevant here. Note that even if the field wasn’t `static`, code of the base class won’t access the subclass’ field if you define a field with the same name there. It would require a non-`static` *method* to have something that you can override in the subclass.

Comment: This is also what I thought. Thanks for sharing. =)

Answer (score 0):

> And then, I can't access to the getClass() method or class member of
>   my type, neither MyParent's.

It has been a while, but I remember Gosu/Guidewire **definitely** support this. They just don't have the same name as their Java counterparts.

You can try around in Gosu Scratchpad and use the auto-complete function of Guidewire Studio to find the necessary methods. Or simply use a decompiler on the root class to see what function they provide, surely there's a *getClass* among them.

As Holger said, it maybe troublesome and "hacky" to use reflection method though. Well, I admit I do that one time, using reflection to develop a customized Contact synchronization between Contact Manager and Claim Center. It is with certain success, though the time to support that solution takes quite long.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is a bit old, and I'm using gw v9, but I found that the only way to use reflection to its full extend (including being able to 'setAccessible') in Gosu is by doing this:

```
var myClass = myObject.Type.getBackingClass()
```

With that you can go on like in java, retrieve declared constructors/fields/methods, static or not, set them accessible and all the other stuff you're not supposed to do.